# layout problem of TOC, index and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, layout

I use the Tufte-Book class and I have layout problems for TOC, index and bibliography, where the margins are shifted on the even pages. Thank you very much in advance for your contribution. Here is the preamble used for the book and a picture of the result :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Principal Title} 
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Me}  
\publisher{Example \'{e}ditions}  
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{height=9.8in,width=6.9in}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{units}

\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}}
\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}
\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{
  \hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}
    }
    {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
    }%
}
\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{%
  \texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% command name
    }%
    {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
    }%

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Generates the index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

This sample book discusses the design of Edward Tufte's
books\cite{Tufte2001,Tufte1990,Tufte1997,Tufte2006}
and the use of the \doccls{tufte-book} and \doccls{tufte-handout} document classes.

\newthought{Il paraît nécessaire} de 

\chapter{Example 1}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\sloppy
\newthought{Il est difficile} de connaître ...  
\chapter{Example 2}
\label{ch:tufte-design}
\section{Example 2.1}
\section{Example 2.2}
\chapter{Example 3}
\section{Example 3.1}
\section{Example 3.2}
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Title 2}
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter
\begin{fullwidth}
\newthought{Il paraît nécessaire} de ...
\end{fullwidth}
\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 1.1}
\chapter{Example 2}
\newthought{La suite est} encore... 
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Title 3}
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 1.1}
\chapter{Example 2}
\chapter{Example 3}
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Épilogue }
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Example 1}
\chapter{Example 2}

\backmatter

\begin{fullwidth}
\bibliography{sample-handout}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{fullwidth}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printindex
\begin{fullwidth}
\tableofcontents
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

And the result is as follows (example for index and TOC, but the same for the TOC and the Bibliography!):

[image]

Comment: Please, post the code instead of images, so we don't have to type everything again.

Comment: Sigur, please explain me how I can post the code !! It is to huge...

Comment: @Phil8544 the idea is to delete as much as possible from the code while the problem still occurs. This removes all irrelevant aspects from the code which makes it easier for people here on the site to see what the problem is, and it is also often the case that you will find the cause and solution of the problem yourself when you are minimizing the code. Admittedly, here this is not so easy, because you need at least one full page of the index to show the problem on the second page. But maybe you can try to make the index start on a page on the right and put just one entry.

Comment: Note that the question may be closed now (it has already 4 votes out of the 5 needed to close), but you can still edit it to provide a good example document. If you do that the question can be re-opened and answered, so don't be disappointed when it is closed now. Also, don't add additional details as answers, but always use the `edit` button below the original question to add and change details (such answers which are not really answers will be removed quickly).