# Layout problems on TOC, index and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, layout

I use the Tufte-Book class and I have layout problems for TOC, index and bibliography, where the margins are shifted on the even pages. Thank you very much in advance for your contribution. Here is the preamble used for the book and a picture of the result :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Principal Title} 
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Me}  
\publisher{Example \'{e}ditions}  
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{height=9.8in,width=6.9in}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{units}

\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}}
\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}
\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{
  \hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}
    }
    {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
    }%
}
\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{%
  \texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {% add the command to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% command name
    }%
    {% add the command and package to the index
      \index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% command name
      \index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% package name
    }%

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Generates the index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

This sample book discusses the design of Edward Tufte's
books\cite{Tufte2001,Tufte1990,Tufte1997,Tufte2006}
and the use of the \doccls{tufte-book} and \doccls{tufte-handout} document classes.

\newthought{Il paraît nécessaire} de 

\chapter{Example 1}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\sloppy
\newthought{Il est difficile} de connaître ...  
\chapter{Example 2}
\label{ch:tufte-design}
\section{Example 2.1}
\section{Example 2.2}
\chapter{Example 3}
\section{Example 3.1}
\section{Example 3.2}
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Title 2}
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter
\begin{fullwidth}
\newthought{Il paraît nécessaire} de ...
\end{fullwidth}
\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 1.1}
\chapter{Example 2}
\newthought{La suite est} encore... 
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Title 3}
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 1.1}
\chapter{Example 2}
\chapter{Example 3}
\begin{fullwidth}
\part{Épilogue }
\end{fullwidth}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Example 1}
\chapter{Example 2}

\backmatter

\begin{fullwidth}
\bibliography{sample-handout}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{fullwidth}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printindex
\begin{fullwidth}
\tableofcontents
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

And the result is as follows (example for index and TOC, but the same for the TOC and the Bibliography!):

[image]

Comment: How does this differ from [Layout problem of ToC, index and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522697/5764) (that was closed)?

Comment: It is the same but with a simplified code... (as the previous is closed, I understood that I have to ask a new question with a simplified code as requested?!)

Comment: A question can be re-opened if it is answerable based on new information that may have stemmed from an edit, or from comments... so, it's not always necessary to re-post something. In this case, a simplified minimal example could have been added to the original post and it would have been sufficient to fall within the re-open review queue.